# programmatically switching wifi with same ssid and different bssid

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I have 2 WiFi with same "SSID" and different bssid and both are open network. I created a program that will try to disconnect from the first WiFi and connect to the second WiFi by setting the different bssid.
It works well in htc and Motorola phone, but it doesn't work at all in Samsung phone. And for htc and Motorola, even the WiFi had successful switched, the native WiFi will automatic help me connect back to first WiFi if I close to the first WiFi.
Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You better showed us adb logs. I have no clue about Samsung's phones behavior - they for instance could have some specific roaming algorithm that conflicts with your application.